# Converting bytea from Postgres to String in Java

Tags: java, string, hibernate, encoding, bytea

Well, i have a column with type bytea in postgres with a lot of character and there works normally, but when i use hibernate to capture this data i get a lot of values diferents from original value.

The original value is: "E02DR0207BR000000105544 FS60"
 But the return is: 37, 51, 49, 51, 54, 52, 52, 53, 50, 51, 48, 51, 50,..
 The return should start with '69' because '69' is 'E' in ASCII table.

**EDIT 1:**

I'm converting byte[] to String in this way:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

        for(byte l : this.linha){
            s.append((char)l);
        }
        return s.toString();
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
The original LINE: 
E16DR0209BR000000187080 FS600               330087420066670000000000000000CN20120901124443

The byte line in JAVA:
%30314452303230394252303030303030313837303830204543462d494620444152554d41204155544f4d4143414f20202020465336303020202020202020202012090120120901313035303020202020323030393039313531313233333030303430343034393439373030343334324d46443030303335343030303335353230313230393031323031323039303130382e30322e37364143313730342030312e30302e3030
```

Comment: check the encoding (UTF-8 or ISO) in DB, probably hibernate is using UTF8 and in the DB it's stored using a different charset

Comment: in DB i'm using LATIN-1 and HIBERNATE we don't have a specify charset defined (in hibernate.cgf.xml).

Comment: so i assume from hibernate you are getting a byte[] and then converting that to a string elsewhere? or how does it go.. are u using byte[] all the way

Comment: I edited the post with the code showing how i convert the byte[] to String. But this is not the problem, because debuggin the code i can see byte[] have wrong values.

Comment: So the error is when you're saving the data. Also, why not user new String(linha, "UTF-8"); to convert the bytes.

Comment: @user2776409 try using new String(bytearray, Charset.forName("UTF-8")).. instead of UTF-8 have your relevant charset (i'm guessing it's ISO_8859_1)

Comment: I tried do it @user2776409 but without success, the problem continue.

Comment: @user2776409 can you post the string you saved to the DB and the one you are getting when reading back

Comment: I edited the post with "ORIGINAL LINE" (from original txt file) and the generated byte line

Comment: @user2776409 can you use Charset.defaultCharset(); and see what's your default charset in the system

Comment: @user2776409 did you ever solved the problem ?